# Cross-Compiling C and C++ application in Windows 7, using MinGW under linux

Tags: c++, c, windows, linux, mingw

I have installed MinGW compiler in Windows 7. GCC version is 4.6.1.

I have Hello World application:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    printf( "Hello World!" );
    return 0;
}
```

How I can compile this application under Windows 7, using MinGW compiler, in order that i can run this application in linux, without recompile.

Comment: ELF and PE executable formats are not really the same binary formats.

Comment: Are MinGW allow to cross-compile application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to distinguish two systems here: The *build* system, which is the one your compiler runs on, and the *host* system, which is the one your executable will run on. MinGW is the GCC compiler for the host system Windows. So, you can compile on Windows for Windows or cross-compile on Linux for Windows. You are looking for a cross compiler for build Windows to host linux, which might be included in Cygwin.

However, generally such things are not well-supported, since Windows is normally used as an end-user only system, not for developing, and UNIX systems for developers. So, you are compiling against the stream here, something not too many people do.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think MinGW provides any cross-compilers that are able to produce linux binaries.

This can be done using Cygwin, they provide cross-compilers so that you can compile linux binaries on a Windows host. You just need to install the necessary packages.